# onTouchListener is not working for real device but working on emulator

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener, android-touch-event

I am finding myself in a problem where I am trying to implement a touch listener in a view. Problem is the **below implementation is perfectly working on my emulator but not working on any real android device. In real device if I am pressing and holding the button it acts like click listener, fires only one time, but not working**. You can find my click event implementation in below.

Note: I want to handle both click and touch listener with this implementation.

Maybe I am missing something here, can anyone please help me finding this solution?

Code

```
     itemBinding.buttonCashOutDecrement.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                decreaseAmountJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
                    while (isActive) {
                        decrementCashOutAmount()
                        delay(CASH_OUT_AMOUNT_INCREASE_DECREASE_DURATION)
                    }
                }
            }

            else -> {
                decreaseAmountJob?.cancel()
                decreaseAmountJob = null
            }
        }
        return@setOnTouchListener true
    }
```